# How can I do these button, you can see in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, skype

I mean these `online, away, busy and offline buttons`, you can see on this image:

[image: Skype]

I want to do that in C#. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called [Thumbnail toolbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#thumbbars) and have a few associated APIs:

- [ITaskbarList3::ThumbBarAddButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391703%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [ITaskbarList3::ThumbBarSetImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [ITaskbarList3::ThumbBarUpdateButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391705%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [THUMBBUTTON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That seems bit harsh but gave some thought to OP :)

Comment: it was literally the first result for “msdn taskbar toolbar”.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Thumbnail toolbars.  Here is a sample from MSDN and in c# (using the  [Windows API CodePack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)).

[Working with Windows 7 Thumbnails](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/08/04/windows-7-thumbnails.aspx)